# Buffer Overflow not working. Don't know why?

Tags: buffer-overflow

Here's the output:

[image]

```
pwndbg> p give_shell
$5 = {void ()} 0x8049217 <give_shell>
```

So if I write this payload `python2 -c "print 'A'*104 + '\x1B\x92\x04\x08' + '\x17\x92\x04\x08'" > fatman`

and run the program in gdb with this payload.
Rather than spawning a shell it gives the following error Idk why.

[image]

Why is it happening?
and how to spawn a shell?
Here's the source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int secret = 0xdeadbeef;
    char name[100] = {0};
    read(0, name, 0x100);
    if (secret == 0x1337) {
        puts("Wow! Here's a secret.");
    } else {
        puts("I guess you're not cool enough to see my secret");
    }
}

void give_shell() {
    system("/bin/sh");
}
```

I compiled it using `gcc -m32 -no-pie -fno-pie -g  -fno-stack-protector feed_me_more.c`

Here's the checksec:

```
pegasus@pegasus:~/Documents/ReSINC_CTF$ checksec --file=a.out
RELRO           STACK CANARY      NX            PIE             RPATH      RUNPATH      Symbols         FORTIFY Fortified       Fortifiable     FILE
Partial RELRO   No canary found   NX enabled    No PIE          No RPATH   No RUNPATH   40 Symbols        No    0               1               a.out
```

Comment: Welcome to the community. Please post a `checksec` output of your compiled binary as well.

Comment: @SirMuffington I had added the checksec. It's an AMD machine

Comment: What is at 0x804921B? I assume you put this in your payload for a reason? The simplest way to determine what is going wrong is to put a breakpoint on (or after)  `read()` and step through. You can then observe the stack being corrupted and which registers are controlled when the main function returns

Comment: 0x804921B is just extra 4 bytes to overwrite the and align the stack.
What the problem is '\x17\x92\x04\x08' this should be executed. This works when I compile as x64. padding till seg fault + 6 bytes (give_shell) function address.
It works as intended. But when I compile as 32. padding till seg fault +  (give_shell) function address. (6,4,8) bytes nothing works the last bytes gets corrupted and modified of the payload

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your alignment is off...

`0x804921B` is in `ECX` and `ESP`
`0x8049217` is in `EDI`

Perhaps you based this on where you had `0x43434343` positioned. However if you pay attention you can see that again, this is the address of `ESP` and the reason you crashed is because `0x43434343` is not initialized memory. In order to actually alter the execution of the program you would need to control the **`EIP`** register, or use a return oriented programming (ROP) payload.

Perhaps try using a longer string to see if you can overwrite `EIP`. Per my comment above you can always set a breakpoint inside `main()` and step through the execution in your debugger to see how you're corrupting the stack and at which point you control which register to determine where you went wrong.

Comment: Do I have to manually check the payload with longer and shorter string?
In x64 it just works fine. I use padding till it gives seg fault. Then I put the 6 byte address where I want the program flow to go. But in x32 The last byte just gets changed for some reason. I had also tried using gdb and breakpoints but couldn't figure it out. As the last byte was getting changed and the library functions are a lot to step into.
I had tried `ni, si` but couldn't fit in my desired payload into EIP

Comment: In x32 the address (and registers) are 32 bits (4 bytes), opcodes are different, etc. You can't just throw the x64 exploit at it and expect it to work

Comment: I am not expecting it to work. Rather I want to learn and know how it will work on x32.